# Angular Material - strange behaviour with multiple css style for mat-select

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using mat-select (among others) Angular Material elements in my app and I'm finding the customization part really tricky.

I need to have some select with white text and other select with black text.

What I've tried is to write two different classes in my style.css file like these:

```
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-form-field-label, .mat-select-value, .mat-select-value-text, .mat-expansion-panel-content { color: white !important; }


.selectBlackTheme .mat-form-field-label, .mat-select-value, .mat-select-value-text, .mat-expansion-panel-content { color: black !important; }
```

Usually it works: I'm applying the selectWhiteTheme or the selectBlackTheme to a mat-form-field and the select will have the choosen color.

The strange behaviour happens when I try to use this approach with a select with fixed options (the other cylces on a list).
This is the select:

```
<mat-form-field class="selectWhiteTheme" >
            <mat-select [(value)]="selectValue" (selectionChange)="onChangeSelect($event.value)">
                <mat-option value="OptionA">OptionA</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="OptionB">OptionB</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

In this case the selectBlackTheme override the selectWhiteTheme but I can't understand why this happens.

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating selectors so naturally the second one takes precedence as it follows the first.

```
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-form-field-label,
.mat-select-value, */ <--this--> /*
.mat-select-value-text,
.mat-expansion-panel-content {
  color: white !important;
}

.selectBlackTheme .mat-form-field-label,
.mat-select-value, */ <same as this etc.--> /*
.mat-select-value-text,
.mat-expansion-panel-content {
  color: black !important;
}
```

should be

```
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-form-field-label,
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-select-value,
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-select-value-text,
.selectWhiteTheme .mat-expansion-panel-content {
  color: white !important;
}

.selectBlackTheme .mat-form-field-label,
.selectBlackTheme .mat-select-value,
.selectBlackTheme .mat-select-value-text,
.selectBlackTheme .mat-expansion-panel-content {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: It's working, thanks! What I do not understand is why I faced that issue only in one select :|